# Image button size for multiple screens

Tags: android, android-layout, size, imagebutton

I am having trouble with android layouts, I want to make app that will support multiple screens, tablets included.
But I am having problem with button sizes.
[image]

How do I set pictures to fit multiple screen sizes?
I have pictures in ressources for Xdpi Mdpi ldpi, but it seems that eclipse is not using them.
Regards

My button looks like this:

```
 <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sound4"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="81dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sound2"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/sound3"
            android:background="@drawable/famas"
            android:onClick="onClick" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 1)please you can use 9-patch image .so this image will stretch automatically 
   on your device height and width.
```

use this link to create 9-pathc image online..
[draw9patch.com](http://draw9patch.com)

or you can use other option:

```
2)button height and width set in all dimension file in values folder for all devices.
```

for ex.values-xhdpi,values-hdpi,values-mdpi...etc

Comment: Way better 9patch generator http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/nine-patches.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:--

create different types of drawables according to your multiple devices.

like this:-

```
  drawable-hdpi,
  drawable-mdpi,
  drawable-ldpi,
  drawable-xhdpi,
  drawable-xxhdpi,
  drawable-sw600dp
  drawable-large-hdpi,etc.
```

You need to use the values folder for this case.make different dimension file and set it according to your device specification.

Like this:--

```
 values-mdpi,
 values-ldpi,
 values-hdpi,
 values-xxdpi,
 values-xlarge,etc.
```